# Do failed Data Factory pipelines keep their original input when rerun?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Say you have a Azure Data Factory pipeline that takes todays date as input, for example as a part of a call to an API. If that pipeline failed yesterday, and is rerun (using the rerun button) today. Will it have the inputs from yesterday or today?

And in the latter case, is there an built-in solution to keep track of this, instead of having to manually enter yesterdays values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data factory pipelines keeps their original input only when it is **constant input** which does not depends on the real time data like dates. When you are re-running the pipelines if you specify the inputs like **dates**(`utcnow()`) it will take the real time data and impacts your current run.

When I checked this from my end, it is taking the updated date time on the re-run i.e. (**Today in your scenario**).

For this kind of real-time data input, **it’s good if our pipeline runs again after the failure**.

If you want to run your pipeline again after first failure you can specify the **retry value** in the activity like below.

[image]